# How to access Google Apps for Business users' calendar free/busy information?

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-apps, saas

I am writing a SaaS (Software as a Service) Java web application that needs to integrate with Google Calendar to meet the following requirement
1. able to get free/busy information of multiple Google Apps for Business domain users. Say, I have two clients using google apps business domain, @abc.com and @def.com.
2. when UserA (owning a@abc.com) logs into my java application, he'll need to view free/busy information of his colleagues (say, b@abc.com) from within my Java application. And, he'll be able to create calendar event from within my Java application.
3. similiarly, UserC (owning c@def.com) logs into my java application, he'll need to view free/busy information of his colleagues (say, d@def.com) from within my Java application. And he'll need to be able to create calendar event from within my Java application.

Essentially, I'm trying to build something similar to Outlook Meeting Scheduling with scheduling assistant (get free/busy info of colleagues) and actual creation of meeting invition in a SaaS way with Google Calendar.

Is it possible to ask user providing username/password of his/her google account, programatically get his colleagues' free/busy info and schedule event on his/her behalf to google calendar? Or, do I have to use Google Calendar API Developer Key + OAuth?

This seems to be a standard use case for SaaS application — a web application that lets users interact with a Google Apps for Business calendar — yet I can't find any documentation on how to make it happen. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not okay to ask users for their passwords directly. Always use Oauth2 instead. When using calendar API, you also need to have a developer key.

As about accessing free-busy (or higher) information for people in the domain, those people will have to have their ACLs set so they share the calendar with everyone in the domain (look at the scope.type domain here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl). Some domains have this setup by default.

If there is an option of getting user's Oauth2 token, you probably want to do that. Another possibility is a service account and a domain-wide delegation: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

A user's primary calendar ID is their Email address in Google Apps. Additionally, a Google Apps Super Admin can automatically see all calendar details for users within their domain regardless of ACLs. Because of this F/B info doesn't need to be shared within the domain if you want/need to avoid this.

Using a Super Admin on both Google Apps accounts, you could GET all user email addresses (calendar IDs) and then GET a list of events based on the calendar IDs. From here, you would just need to mark off the times as F/B in your Java web app.